# Performance optimization in CUDA - Which of these algorithms should I use?

Tags: performance, cuda

I have an algorithm which consists two major tasks. Both tasks are embarrassingly parallel. So I can port this algorithm on CUDA by one of the following way.

```
>Kernel<<<
Block,Threads>>>()  \\\For task1  
cudaThreadSynchronize();  
>Kerne2<<<
Block,Threads>>>()  \\\For task2
```

Or I can do following thing.

```
>Kernel<<<
Block,Threads>>>()  
{  
    1.Threads work on task 1.  
    2.syncronizes across device.  
    3.Start for task 2.  
}
```

One can note that in first method, we'll have to come back to CPU while in second trend we'll have to use synchronization across all blocks in CUDA. Paper in [IPDPS 10](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5470477) says that second method, with proper care can perform better. But in general which method should be followed?

Comment: I'm getting results in favor of first method, sometimes in favor of second method. What is recommended in literature?

Comment: In that case, make sure the second method follows the paper well to see if it takes the edge. If both are still relatively the same (and this is with the real data you'll be working with), keep whichever you want. Just try to keep the ability to switch them around available to you, so you can always test along the way.

Comment: why don't you want using streams for that ? Fermi supports concurrent kernel execution, so you can launch both kernels at the same time (if they do not depend on one another of course). Otherwise in my opinion, interblock sync is a really nasty thing: in that paper you mentioned it only works when there is 1-to-1 mapping of thread blocks to multiprocessors. I would not use it honestly..

Comment: To be very frank to say, paper idea is not working in reality. On some cases it is taking too much time so driver is terminating kernel execution. I thought of streams but in my case task2 is dependent on task1 so only 2 solutions..either come back to CPU or manage to achieve sync across blocks(anyhow). Interblock sync is good when number of blocks are small but it is unreliable if we have large number of  blocks, and this is evident because while loop in interblock sync mechanism can kill time.

Comment: as a classical optimization pattern, you can also think of splitting your data in chunks which do not depend on one another during the kernel calls. Then every chunk can be processed in a separate stream giving some partial overlap in kernel executions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently any officially supported method for synchronizing across thread blocks withing a single kernel execution in the CUDA programming model. Methods of doing so, in my experience, lead to brittle code that can lead to incorrect behavior under changing circumstances such as running on different hardware, changing driver and CUDA release versions, etc.

Just because something is published in an academic publication does not mean it is a safe idea for production code.

I recommend you stick with your method 1, and I ask you this: have you determined that separating your computation into two separate kernels is really causing a performance problem?  Is the cost of a second kernel launch definitely the bottleneck?

Comment: "have you determined that separating your computation into two separate kernels is really causing a performance problem?"  --Not exactly, but idea of coming back to CPU is not good in my app, I want to launch N threads for set of tasks and forget from CPU side(so that CPU thread can do some other useful work).So I was wondering whether it is possible to sync across all threads on device, but if sync is costly then I've to use something "intelligent" to so that my app shouldn't be required to come to CPU during execution.

Comment: at harrism: I've read your chapter in GPU gems 3 about prefix sum, but I havn't seen source code though. In that implementation which of the above method you use?

Comment: To your first comment, you may be interested in CUDA Dynamic Parallelism, available in the upcoming Kepler GK110 GPU -- it enables kernels to launch other kernels (among other things). To your second comment: I always use method 1: the only safe way to block sync, in my opinion, is by launching another kernel.

Comment: Is GK110 available for purchase?

Comment: Not yet.  Hence "upcoming".  But the CUDA 5.0 release candidate is out so you can read the documentation...

Comment: Actually, I read doc and I'm using CUDA 5 only, but dynamic parallelism is something that should be supported from hardware so without hardware I'll  not be able to do anything, if I'm not wrong.